# Duplicate Prefix Error in Jsp page with Struts

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, struts

i am creating and Configuring the Struts for the first time, when I place the following Code in my jsp page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
```

I am getting the error when i move the mouse over the 1st Line **"Duplicate Prefix "html"**

When I move the mouse over the 2nd Line, I am getting as "**Duplicate Prefix "html"**
Similarly for 3rd and 4th Line,

Can any one tell me why is this error all about

Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the struts2 tag, this is struts 1 (classic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes eclipse forgets to cleanup, especially with JSP errors.

When you run the application, do you get the same error? If not, then it is an eclipse issue.

I do this when I get this persistent JSP errors that are not valid: Select All, Cut, Save, Paste, Save.
Did you try cleaning the project? (Project Menu -> Clean)
Restarting eclipse may also solve this.